# If $A$ is measurable does $m^*(B)=m^*(A)$ imply that $B$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $A$ is measurable and $m^*(A\Delta B)=0$ then $B$ is measurable.  I've concluded that $m^*(B)=m^*(A)$, but I'm not sure if this is sufficient to show that $B$ is measurable.

**EDIT:** $m^*$ is the outer measure (Lebesgue measure when restricted to the family of measurable sets).

Comment: What exactly is $m*$ here?  How are you defining measurable?  This is clearly false for the Borel sigma algebra, but is true for Lebesgue and m* the usual outer measure.

Comment: I know there are Lebesgue nonmeasurable subsets of $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue outer measure $1$ (for an extreme example, see my comments to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115026)), so $A$ measurable and m*(A) = m*(B) does not imply that $B$ is measurable.

Answer (score 4):

No.  Given any nonmeasurable set $B$, the interval $[0,m^*(B)]$ is measurable and has outer measure equal to $m^*(B)$.  See Dave L. Renfro's comment for a note about more interesting examples that may better answer why this method is not enough.

You can use $B=B\setminus A\cup (A\setminus (A\setminus B))$ to help solve the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in general (when the measurable space and outer measure are arbitrary) even the original statement is false. Consider an example when $A$ is measurable and $B = A\cup N$ where $N$ is not a measurable set, but $m^*(N) = 0$.

Comment: @Jonas: yes, I decided to remove them

Comment: But if you have $m$ complete you can not have $m^*(N)=0$ and $N$ non-measurable.

Comment: @tom: indeed, it is true. Though, in general measures are not complete

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $m$ is Lebesgue measure. $m$ is complete than sets $A \Delta B$, $A\setminus B$,$B\setminus A$ are measurable.

So $B = (A\setminus A\Delta B) \cup (B\setminus A)$.

$B$ is union of two measurable sets so it is measurable.